# Errors after upgrading to wordpress 3.6

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I have issue after upgrading my wordpress to 3.6 see below for errors which displays on wordpress admin panel not on front of website.

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function ‘regis_options’ not found or invalid function name in wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406

Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by (output started at wp-includes/plugin.php:406) in wp-includes/option.php on line 571

Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by (output started at wp-includes/plugin.php:406) in wp-includes/option.php on line 572

Comment: Those are warnings, not critical errors - were they there before? What plugin causes them, can you see in the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bulk Disable plugins - do error messages disappear?

- activate each plugin, one by one to diagnose problem.

During the upgrade, did your connection time out?

Can you please supply a link (if you wish, use an URL shortener for privacy)?

Comment: Sorry i can not turn off all the plugin because if i do that so my data and setting will be lost and for sharing a link with you that I cann't because as i described in mail thread it is displaying in wordpress admin panel.

Comment: Got the issue the "WP Content Copy Protection" plugin is not compatible with wordpress 3.6 that i have disabled that plugin and THAT WORKS...

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it worked for you. Good idea too, that plugin only represses people from sharing online.

Comment: Now plugin author has changed code and that is working on Wordpress 3.6 also so anyone can use that now. Thank you Plugin Author...